# how to fix the eslint indent error in vscode?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, formatter, vetur

sorry, my English is not good, but I need to know how to fix it.

I try to use every indent rules, it doesn't work...

I wish everything is well when I use Vetur formatter.

please tell me how to fix it, thanks

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs#disallow-mixed-spaces-and-tabs-for-indentation-no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

[my question snippets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1N84.jpg)

[question description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuxTi.jpg)

[my vscode setting.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2XKY.jpg)

[my eslint rules setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASiNg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `offsetTernaryExpressions` to your ESLint `indent` rule config.

**`.eslintrc`**

```json
rules: {
    'indent': [2, 2, {
        'SwitchCase': 1,
        'offsetTernaryExpressions': true
    }]
}
```

[More information on this configuration option](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#offsetternaryexpressions)